# invalid operands to binary - (have 'int *' and 'int **')

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a[]= {10,20,30,40,50,60};
int *p[]= {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5};
int **pp=p;
pp++;
printf("%d,%d,%d", pp-p,*pp-a, **pp);
*pp++;
printf("%d,%d,%d", pp-p, *pp-p, *pp-p);
++*pp;
printf("%d,%d,%d", pp-p, *pp-a, **pp);
++**pp;
printf("%d,%d,%d", pp-p, *pp-a, **pp);
}
```

it's showing this error:

```
invalid operands to binary - (have 'int *' and 'int **')
     printf("%d,%d,%d", pp-p, *pp-p, *pp-p);
 invalid operands to binary - (have 'int *' and 'int **')
     printf("%d,%d,%d", pp-p, *pp-p, *pp-p);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of these substractions? (what do expect as results?) The compiler tells you that your various pointer-types are incompatible (different levels of indirection) but I have no clue on how to fix this without knowing the intent.

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste error to me. The second printf doesn't look like all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*pp-p`, you cannot subtract a `int**` from an `int*` since they are not compatible types. It should be `pp-p`.

Also please note that in order to print addresses with printf, you should cast the pointers to `void*` and print using `%p`.